# Does WebGL support color formats with more than 32bit?

Tags: colors, format, webgl

I can't seem to find any texture format with more than 32 bit (GL.RGBA). Is this not supported by WebGL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By 32bit you mean where each element is 32bit itself or each element is 8bits and in sum they are 32 bits (8 bits of red, 8 bits of green, 8 bits of blue, 8 bits of alpha)?

In any case there are extensions for 32bit float formats in WebGL1 so 32bits of red, 32bits of green, 32bits of blue, 32bits of alpha which is 128bit texture format.

Those extensions are

- [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/). Let's you create 32bits per channel floating point textures
- [OES_texture_half_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_half_float/) Let's you create 16bits per channel half floating point textures
- [OES_texture_float_linear](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float_linear/). Let's you set filtering to something other than `gl.NEAREST` when using a floating point texture
- [OES_texture_half_float_linear](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_half_float_linear/). Let's you set filtering to something other than `gl.NEAREST` when using a half floating point texture

To use any of these you have to enable each one as in

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
   alertNoFloatSupportOrFallbackToOtherOption();
}
```

Pretty much all desktop GPUs support all 4. Mobile devices usually only support the half formats and sometimes don't support filtering.

In WebGL2 both formats exist automatically but the ability to filter them (`OES_texture_float_linear`, and `OES_texture_half_float_linear`) is still optional.

Also many mobile devices do not allow rendering to float or half float textures where as laptop/desktops usually do. To check if they allow rendering try to enable `WEBGL_color_buffer_float` on WebGL1 or `EXT_color_buffer_float` on WebGL2.

Yet another related optional feature is whether or not you can enable blending with floating point textures. That extension is `EXT_float_blend`. It's generally available on laptop/desktop computers but not on mobile even though mobile (at least iOS since iPhone6S) allows rendering to 32bit float textures since Apple switched their WebGL implementation to be based on [ANGLE/Metal](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/).

Comment: For future readers, a lot of these extensions have been renamed. Mozilla keeps a reference of all extensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Using_Extensions. Alternatively you can use `gl.getSupportedExtensions();` to get all available extensions. On my browser this extension called `EXT_COLOR_BUFFER_FLOAT`

Comment: none of the extensions mentioned in this answer have been renamed.